# Python multithreading: Is the thread that is notified through condition.notify() assured to take the lock?

Tags: python, multithreading

Question in the title:
When a thread goes on the wait() function, it goes into wait-c, and when another thread that currently has acquired the same lock of the same condition as the first thread executes the notify() function, the first thread that was in wait-c is now in wait-l, so it's waiting for the second thread to release the lock for it.

But if there are other threads waiting on that same lock, is the thread that was notified assured to take the lock when the thread that used notify() releases the lock at the end?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#condition-objects)

Comment: I've read the documentation, so as I understand it: The answer to my question is No, the notified thread simply moves to the 'waiting room' of the threads that want to acquire that lock. The use of the while in this example it's also because of this, because if its turn doesn't come as soon as the thread that notifies it releases the lock then other threads might take the lock instead and do something that wouldn't let that awakened thread go on with his code again once its turn comes. Am I wrong?

Comment: @massimo, You are not wrong. That's the main reason why it's always smart to call `wait()` in a loop. In many real-world programs, there will be more than one thread waiting for the same thing. Just because `wait()` returned, doesn't guarantee that one of the _other_ waiting threads didn't sneak in and steal whatever it was that the caller was awaiting.